# Share a URL on Twitter with thumbnail

Tags: twitter, html, thumbnail

I know that adding `<meta property="og:image" content="<URL-HERE>" />` to an HTML page makes it generate a thumbnail image when sharing the URL on Facebook:

[image]

How to have the same with Twitter?

<sub>How should I modify my HTML page to have an image automatically added when I share an URL in a tweet?</sub>

Answer (score 3):

```
<meta property="twitter:image" content="<URL-HERE>" />
```

You can use this meta tag for twitter. For more informations see here: https://dev.twitter.com/cards/markup

Answer (score 0):

Put https://2fb.me before the URL

I.E https://2fb.me/https://twitter.com/shareU/status/936789197456777217

and share the URL

Comment: So this would share an URL on Twitter through FB?

Comment: no the opposite. It shares to facebook from twitter.